# Is there a way to prevent CL_SALV_TABLE from removing leading spaces?

Tags: abap, alv

Is there a way to prevent an instance of `CL_SALV_TABLE` from removing leading spaces in the display?

I have the following piece of code in which I put a single space in front of `Master` text and two spaces in front of `Slave` text.

```
REPORT zzy.

CLASS lcl_main DEFINITION FINAL CREATE PRIVATE.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    CLASS-METHODS:
      main.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_main IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD main.
    TYPES: BEGIN OF l_tys_test,
      name  TYPE string,
      value TYPE i,
    END OF l_tys_test,
    l_tyt_test TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF l_tys_test WITH EMPTY KEY.

    DATA(lt_test) = VALUE l_tyt_test(
      ( name = `Root` value = 0 )
      ( name = ` Master` value = 1 )
      ( name = `  Slave` value = 2 )
    ).

    cl_salv_table=>factory(
      IMPORTING
        r_salv_table = DATA(lo_salv_table)
      CHANGING
        t_table = lt_test
    ).
    lo_salv_table->display( ).
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  lcl_main=>main( ).
```

Unfortunately the leading spaces get trimmed in the view.

[image: Spaces get trimmed]

In this [tutorial](http://scn.sap.com/community/abap/blog/2015/07/24/salv-tree-to-excel-xlsx) the guy seems to have made it somehow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
lo_salv_table->get_columns( )->get_column( 'NAME' )->set_leading_spaces( abap_true ).
```